# Simplest networking restart

Tags: wireless

I'm having a problem with wireless dropouts in Kubuntu 14.10, and a plethora of solutions have appeared online, each suggesting that the others are mistaken. But I have a simpler question: in order to test a solution, I need to restart networking.  What is the simplest and least disruptive way to do that?  It shouldn't be necessary to log out.

Answer (score 2):

This command should restart basic networking.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

As a side note, this won't restart any other daemons. Some fixes might require a full restart, and this command won't necessarily replace that, but it will restart networking.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to run these two commands

```
sudo service networking restart
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Or an other option

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart
```

A log out or something isn't necessary.

---

Or in Ubuntu 15.04 you should use Systemd:

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Comment: `service network-manager restart` is for 14.04, if user is on 15.04, he'd probably need `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` . You might wanna add it. Otherwise - good answer

Comment: @Serg :) good answer with a -1 o_O But the commands currently working in 15.04 :)

Comment: @Serg added you recommendations.

Comment: don't know who may have downvoted, but I evened it out. +1'ed

Comment: On 14.10 I get this: pwa@Aspire-E1-731:~$ sudo service networking restart
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking

Comment: Sorry for the misformatting:`sudo service networking restart

Comment: Try this command: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`